# How to set focus on second Accessibility element?

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I've tried to set the focus to the second element on an alert view:

```
 UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, secondElement);
```

It works on iOS 12 and before, but after iOS 13, the focus will initially be on the second element, but will soon be on the first.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there's a bit of a race between your Post Notification and one posted by the system when a new view appears. You may need to delay your notification, which is a bit of a hack, but it usually works.

I think you want to post a `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification` if you're opening an alert. There is relatively little difference between the `screenChanged` and `layoutChanged` notification types – they both cause VoiceOver to refresh its cache of what its interacting with on the screen – but there is a difference in their default behaviour.

A `screenChanged` notification should fire when an entirely new screen appears, and it will cause focus to move to the first focusable element on the new screen.

A `layoutChanged` notification should fire when a part of the current screen changes, such as toggling an expand-collapse panel, but it *does not* move focus to an element by default. If you wish, you provide the element to receive focus as the second argument of the `layoutChanged` notification.

In Swift, this might look something like:

```
if UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: secondElement)
    }
}
```

In Objective C:

```
if (UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1.0) {
        UIAccessibilityPostNotification(
            UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification,
            secondElement);
    }
}
```

**Important note:**
Be careful changing focus in this way. While opening an alert, it *may* be acceptable to change focus in this way, *but* you must test to make sure that the content of the Alert is actually announced by VoiceOver when opening it while using this technique. It may be that VoiceOver users miss the message. Generally, setting an unexpected focus position can cause more problems than it's worth for people who rely on such software.

Comment: I've actually tried this, but it doesn't always work. My Alert was placed on a custom UIWindow. After iOS 13, there were a lot of problems, like when I called alert from WKWebview, the focus was often not anywhere on the screen, but it read the content of the first element. Do you know why? And do you know how to get the focus on the element exactly?

Comment: By the way, why use UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification? What's the difference between them?

Comment: I will update my answer with details of `screenChanged` versus `layoutChanged`.

Comment: It still sounds like a lower level notification is overriding the notification you are posting, causing VoiceOver's focus to be set according to the default behaviour, which is to focus on the first element. If you fire `layoutChanged` instead of `screenChanged`, it should stop this lower level notification from overriding your notification.

Comment: I changed the `layoutChanged` according to what you said, but It still focused on the first element, which is really strange. Also, using `layoutChanged` has a high chance of focusing on the element but not broadcasting it. Do you know why?

Comment: I’m afraid I’m out of ideas.